# dotnet command is not found in my Mac m1 terminal

Tags: c#, .net, bash, visual-studio-code, zsh

I have downloaded .net5 from official website, but `dotnet` command isn't recognised by my terminal.

Here's what I have found after some research-

1. my dotnet folder is present in `/usr/local/share/dotnet`
2. I used this command but it didn't work `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet`

   1. now whenever I enter `dotnet` in terminal it shows `zsh: permission denied: dotnet`
3. I also tried this command and it didn't work `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet`

   1. now whenever I enter `dotnet` in terminal it shows `zsh: command not found: dotnet`
4. when I open my .cs file in vscode it shows error as `The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path.`

here's a screenshot for reference [image]

What should I do :(

Comment: Did you install SDK? `dotnet` tool is a part of SDK, not runtime.

Comment: yeah I have installed the SDK from here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-5.0.403-macos-x64-installer?journey=vs-code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Had the same(ish) issue after installing .NET 6 broke my current .NET 5 installation.

I fixed it by:

**1. removing all files of the current dotnet installation.**

This is done by deleting the `dotnet` folder located in `/usr/local/share/`

(Navigate there using Finders 'go to' feature, or just delete it using the terminal)

**2. reinstalling the dotnet sdk**

download from https://dotnet.microsoft.com

**3. adding a symlink to the current dotnet executable.**

Arm64 (M1/M2/M3 Macs):

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

x64 (Intel Macs):

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: thanks JaggerJo it worked!! Can you tell me what does the command does?

Comment: There are a few dirs where executable files are expected. It is possible to add dirs, but we can also add links to executable files - instead of the actual files.

In this case we add a link to the dotnet executable file in a directory that is searched by default.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well. Oddly I had to delete an existing executable named *dotnet* in */usr/local/bin/* first

Comment: I already have .net6 as my first installed version so all I had to do was run:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/

and it worked. Thank you

Comment: MacPro M1 MacOS 12, doesn't work

Comment: I have MacPro M1, the problem is the folder /usr/local/bin never existed on my Mac tried creating the path & performed step #3. it worked! @HamedZakeryMiab you can give a try.

Comment: For M3 with Sonoma:
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 3):

I was having issues today with this on my MacBook Air M1. Saw that lot of people were suggesting to use

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

However, this didn't work for me. I looked in the `/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet` dir, and the `x64/` dir was not there. Which means that linkng was not going to happen.

So my solution was to take out the `x64/` from the path from the command. Then I ran the `dotnet` command to verify. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I did not had the access to share folder, but you can grant access to the local user.

The dotnet is located in **/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet** on ARM64
So be sure to symbolic link the path right.

Also **sudo dotnet** if running terminal inside Visual Studio Code